# How to convert HML to SML with a flow formula

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, web-to-case, lightning-email-template, text-template

I'm trying to work around a requirement with the [Send Better Email Flow Action](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/) to have a recipient contact record, when using email templates.

My use case, is that I'm sending 'case opened' emails to people submitting access via web-to-case. I want to do this with lightning email templates. There is no problem when WTC matches a single contact, but when multiple, or no contacts are found, the contact details are saved in the *web* fields, i.e. `Web Email`, and no contact record is referenced on the case, limiting me to using flow text templates in the SBE flow action.

To reduce maintenance complexity, I want to avoid having to use both lightning email templates, and text templates to store the email body. I'd prefer to use lightning email templates in all cases. I have my lightning email templates set up already, and they are HML templates.

My thinking is that I could reference the `HtmlValue` of the email template as the flow text template body, however the merge fields won't work now, since the text templates use SML.

I created the formula below to convert the HML to SML-like syntax, by substituting the `{{{` and `}}}` characters in the email template `HtmlValue` with `{!` and `}` respectively.

```
SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE({!Get_Email_Template.HtmlValue}
    , "{{{", "{!")
, "}}}", "}")
```

I set the API name of my Get Records elements to the same as the object name, so converting that wouldn't be required.

To recap with an example, the email template `HtmlValue` references the HML merge field `{{{Case.CaseNumber}}}`. I want to convert this to `{!Case.CaseNumber}`. The actual output of my formula is `Case.CaseNumber}}`.

Why isn't this working? Am I asking too much of the text template and formula functions in Salesforce for this kind of merge field conversion?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like adding the `{!` first was confusing the markup handling of the text template, leading to the unexpected output. Simply swapping the order of the formula substitutions ended up working for me.

```
SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE({!Get_Email_Template.HtmlValue}
    , "}}}", "}")
, "{{{", "{!")
```